# jquery $(this).attr(…) returns undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, find, switch-statement

I'm trying to get the title of an `option` element, but it keeps returning undefined. This also happens for `$(this).attr("name")`…and `$(this).attr("value")`, but curiously `$(this).val()` works (as expected). Yet, I'm able to set the value with `$(this).attr("value", "baz")`.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jshado1/JgAJC/1/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`this` points to the `<select>` element. For the selected option, use:

```
this.options[this.selectedIndex]
```

Full code (you can safely unwrap `$opt`'s jquery wrapper, and use `$opt.title` and `$opt.name`, these are safe across all browsers):

```
$('select').change(function() {
    var $opt = $(this.options[this.selectedIndex]),
        t = $opt.attr("title"),
        n = $opt.attr("name"),
        v = this.value;
    $("#name").text("name: "+n);
    $("#title").text("title: "+n);
    $("#value").text("value: "+v);
});
```

Another method, the jQuery-way is:

```
$('select').change(function() {
    var $opt = $(this).children(':selected'),
        t = $opt.attr("title"),
        n = $opt.attr("name"),
        v = this.value;
    $("#name").text("name: "+n);
    $("#title").text("title: "+n);
    $("#value").text("value: "+v);
});
```

Comment: Here's the demo, by the way: http://jsfiddle.net/JgAJC/5/. I also replaced `"title: "+n` with `"title"+t`, so that it works as intended.

Comment: Oh yes, I tried to post the updated link (I noticed right after I posted), but jsfiddle didn't want to update. Thanks! Works great!

Comment: really cool solution, but do you understand why $(this,">option :selected")..... doesn't work in this circumstances ?

Comment: @sirlancelot `$(this)` doesn't actually query the dom... it just boxes `this` in a jquery object.

Comment: @EvilP Because You have swapped the selectors, and added a space between `option` and `:selected`. Spaces separate sub-selectors, so remove it. Furthermore, `$(selector, context)` is the right signature (equivalent to `.find`). Since you're using `>option`, the selector is equivalent to `$(this).children('option:selected');`.

Answer (score 3):

This is because you have mistaken what `this` represents in your code. The `this` represents the `select` element that has changed. Because the select node doesnt have a `title` attribute, it is undefined. What you would need to do is enumerate over the options list of the select and find the item that is selected. Then, you can operate on that item to find information like so:

```
 var element = $(this.options[this.selectedIndex]);

 element.attr('title');
```